# Simple jQuery/CSS3 Menu with Transitions

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a simple menu with a nice transition effect using either jQuery or CSS3. The problem is that I want 3 buttons with 3 different hover and active states (i.e., different colours). What's better though? jQuery or CSS3? I know IE9 doesn't support CSS3 so should one use that right now? This menu seems easier to implement with CSS3 than jQuery, I think. See my menu [here](http://jsfiddle.net/23zms/) which was created using a jQuery tutorial I found [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/stylish-navigation-menu-jquery/).

As you can see, the second button (red) doesn't show up smoothly, while the third button has a  smoother transition. I need this effect for all three, but each button will have a different colour.

Is this how you would do the same effect with CSS3?

```
.button1 {
    background-image: url('test.png');
 }

.button1:hover {
    background-image: url('test_hover.png');
    transition: background-image .15s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .15s ease-in;
```

Hope I explained everything right. If you need any clarifications, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: CSS alone is always preferable when it is achieveable. CSS3 is less so, because it requires modern browser and the spec isn't nailed down yet. Try implementing the basic functionality with CSS, then add CSS3 transitions as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about using CSS3 transitions is that they will be ignored if the browser doesn't recognize them. In which case, the transition will simply regress to an instant flip.

I'd recommend using a [sprite image](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). Then instead of changing the image on hover... just change the image position.

```
.button1 {
    background-image: url('test_sprite.png');
    background-position: top;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
    transition: background-position .15s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: background-position .15s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-position .15s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .15s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: background-position .15s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out and let you know. So in the HTML, I need to give this class, `button1`, to an image, correct? As in `<a href="#"><img class="button1" alt=""/></a>`. And do I need to specify the dimensions of the sprite image in the CSS?